# login problem in the Android Mobile app

Tags: mobile, login, sdk, issue, standard

Steps to reproduce

1. Login into the application.
2. Do complete few service appointments assigned to the technician.
3. Logout from the application
4. keep the login page open. do not kill the application and do not
   switch off the mobile app.
5. Next day, login into the application

The error

> 'Invalid login'

will appear on the screen or Showing the standard salesforce login screen instead of mobile view

Comment: Just to clarify - you have used ``sdk`` tag - does your problem appears in custom mobile app or out-of-the-box Salesforce Mobile App? If the latter - you need to provide more details about specific part of your application, ex. the code which stands behind the login page.

Comment: This problem appears in the custom mobile app and i didn't test this behaviour in the out-of-the-box Salesforce Mobile App. Earlier i have created Salesforce support case # 25299580 with screenshots and videos. we could provide specific part of code or configuration if required.

Comment: The purpose of this community is to help solving salesforce-related problems so you should share a code where Mobile SDK is used.